# Appending to a dictionary of JSON

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2, swifty-json

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me discern what exactly I'm doing wrong in my code, when converting my project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.

I am trying to download and parse JSON data (using an updated branch of SwiftJSON), but continue to receive the error **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Minion' with an argument list of type '(minionDetails: Element)'**.

It seems I was able to convert the rest of my code successfully, but this line is holding me back from building the project.

**Minion.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Minion : NSObject, NSCoding {

var name: String?
var age: String?

class func fetchMinionData() -> [Minion] {

    var myURL = "http://myurl/test.json"

    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

    var dataError: NSError?

    let data: NSData?
    do {
        data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: dataURL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        dataError = error
        data = nil
    }

    let minionJSON = JSON(data!)
    var minions = [Minion]()

    for minionDictionary in minionJSON {
        minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
    //THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR
    }
    return minions
}

init(minionDetails: JSON) {

    name = minionDetails["san"].string
    age = minionDetails["age"].string
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String
    age = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("age")as? String
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encodeObject(age, forKey: "age")
}  
}
```

I assume I am appending something wrong, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SwiftyJSON object named `minionJSON` is actually a dictionary, so you have to use the value for the key in each iteration instead of the whole object. In our example we don't need the key so I've replaced it with the `_` placeholder.

```
for (_ , minionDictionary) in minionJSON {
    minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it!  Thanks so much!  Worked great!